# Hazelcast replicatedmap not cached on client?

Tags: hazelcast

We are using a Hazelcast replicatedmap to keep track of the state of a small number (<100) of state entities.

Only a few instances (writers) will be updating state, while the rest are only reading them.
We have many more lookups than changes, and it is ok for updates to be seen a bit late  by readers (seconds late, not days). For performance reasons, it is important that the readers do not need to do a network call for a lookup, thus the replicatedmap.

Currently, the readers are hazelcast clients. But it looks to me like they are then not keeping a local copy of the data in the replicatedmap?

Do we need to make them members instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a client-server architecture, you might find [near-cache](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.0-beta-2/performance/near-cache.html#latest-banner) a better solution.

The servers would host the data in an [IMap](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/5.0-BETA-2/javadoc/com/hazelcast/map/IMap.html) rather than a [ReplicatedMap](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/5.0-BETA-2/javadoc/com/hazelcast/replicatedmap/ReplicatedMap.html), each client would have a copy.
Clients would use their copy when available, and only go to the servers for items they don't have or that change.

Comment: But the problem is we would readers to update quickly when state change - so using a push mechanism. So if we use a near-cache, we would need a 1 second timeout.

Comment: Near-cache has some configurables that might help (see here)[https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.0-beta-2/performance/near-cache.html#near-cache-invalidation] which might be enough. Alternatively there is [continuous query](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.0-beta-2/query/continuous-query-cache.html#latest-banner) which is similar but based on selecting entries by attributes rather than by key.

Comment: Thank you - I had not noticed those options. It seems near-cache is the way to go for us.